# Cannot run sudo update-manager

Tags: updates, gtk, locale, ascii

I cannot run sudo update-manager. I dont know whats wrong. Do you know?

```
(precise)acer@localhost:~$ sudo update-manager
[sudo] password for acer: 

(process:5761): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
WARNING:root:estimate_kernel_size_in_boot() returned '0'?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 64, in <module>
help=_("Directory that contains the data files").decode(enc))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 17: ordinal not           in range(128)
(precise)acer@localhost:~$ 


(precise)acer@localhost:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "sv_SV:en",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_MESSAGES = "sv_SV.UTF-8",
LANG = "sv_SV.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales...
en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date
en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date
sv_FI.UTF-8... up-to-date
sv_SE.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
(precise)acer@localhost:~$
```

I use swedish language, but not swedish keyboard layout beacuse i dont know how to install that.

Answer (score 2):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager
```

then try again.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your locale is incorrectly set; there is no "sv_SV.UTF-8" locale.

Please use `System Settings -> Language Support` to select Swedish for both the language and the regional formats. Then, after you have logged out and re-logged in, try to run update-manager again.

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard Layout` to set a keyboard layout that matches your physical keyboard.